# Iteration Through tuple of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to iterate through a tuple of dictionaries using Python, get the value that I'm looking for and then modify another dictionary with that value. Example:

```
Dict = {'1': 'one', '2': 'three'}

Tuple = ({'1': 'one', '5': 'five'}, {'4': 'four', '2': 'two'})
```

My goal is to modify `Dict` and replace `'three'` with `'two'` from my second dictionary in my tuple.

I know how to iterate through dictionaries using for loops and `dict.items()`, but i can't seem to do so with tuple...

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Will `Dict` have all of the key/value pairs from the `Tuple` dicts?

Comment: my Dict will not necessarily include all of the key/value from the Tuple dicts but Tuple dicts will certainly have all of the key/value from Dict..Hope that makes sense

Comment: What should the program do if `Tuple` contains two dictionaries with a key that matches a key in `Dict`, for example: `Tuple = ({'1': 'one', '5': 'five'}, {'4': 'four', '2': 'two'}, {'2': 'six'})`?

Comment: @MaxSpencer good question but I will never have that.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check each dict `d` for the key and then set `Dict["2"]` equal to `d["2"]`.

```
Dict = {'1': 'one', '2': 'three'}

Tuple = ({'1': 'one', '5': 'five'}, {'4': 'four', '2': 'two'})

for d in Tuple:
    if "2" in d:
        Dict["2"] = d["2"]
```

If you have multiple dicts in Tuple that have the same key the value will be set to the last dict you encounter. If you wanted the first match you should `break` in the if.

```
Dict = {'1': 'one', '2': 'three'}

Tuple = ({'1': 'one', '5': 'five'}, {'4': 'four', '2': 'two'})
for d in Tuple:
    if "2" in d:
        Dict["2"] = d["2"]
        break # get first match
```

If you want the last match it would be better start at the end of Tuple:

```
for d in reversed(Tuple):
    if "2" in d:
        Dict["2"] = d["2"]
        break # last dict in Tuple that has the key
```

Comment: i dont need two for loops on d?

Comment: Seems unlikely that the OP literally just wants to replace items with key '2', can you clarify if this is the goal @Froodo?

Comment: @Froodo, no, `if "2" in d` will see if the key exists in the dict, there is no need to iterate over the keys and it is actually less efficient .

Comment: @MaxSpencer, that is irrelevant, the logic is what is important. They also commented stating they know the specific key they want to look for.

Comment: @MaxSpencer, I already know what keys i need to replace everytime. I have a marker that defines that since i dont want to modify them everytime. :)

Comment: @Froodo, a `key in d` is `0(1)` iterating over the dict keys is `O(n)`

Comment: What happens if instead of Dict, i have another Tuple and i need to perform same logic...i need to iterate through both tuples right? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @Froodo, yep, but still use `if key in d`, don't iterate over the dict.